# Access an instance in another running Java program?

Tags: java

I am having a main class called ProccesA, after I run it I am starting another main class (when ProccesA is still running for his own) and I wish to get the instance of ProccesA to use it in my class, can some one direct me how to do that ?

Comment: Is this *really* desired? (To have *multiple* JVM processes running?) If so, look up "remoting".

Comment: ProccesaA i run for his one and has some methods i need, in my class i wish to use his instance for my uses..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes are not like threads: you cannot get access to instances of classes running in different *processes*, because they are in a different address space. You need to use [interprocess communication facilities](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzaha/interpro.htm) to communicate to other processes.

Comment: i saw that i can use :  theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(); but  what should i write in exec ? and after i have the process how i can use his methods ?

Comment: @eran10 Runtime.exec(command) returns an instance of [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object. It is not the process itself, just a *representation* of a running process. Its abilities are rather limited - you can get the inputs and outputs of a running process, get its exit code, and that's pretty much it.

Comment: so i wont help me here because i need to get access to ProccesA instance class so i can use his methods, any ideas how ?

Comment: @eran10 That's what I said in the answer - there is no way to do it, because it is running in a separate, completely isolated and independent process.

Answer (score 1):

Both processes execute in different JVMs, and so use different class loaders. You can't access them directly.

You could however, use RMI to expose the required classes in one of the processes, and access them that way.

Comment: ok, i am using RMI but how can i expose class and access it ?